# emacs org mode define a function in src block and call it

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

is there a method/package to use the following syntax to define and call a function?

```python
#+NAME: retX
#+BEGIN_SRC python :var x=5
def retX (x):
    return x
#+END_SRC
```

... Some text later...

```python
#+begin_src pyton
<<retX(x=6)>>
#+end_src
```

I am not a huge fan of being limited to

```python
#+name: retX
#+begin_src python :var x=5
return x
#+end_src
```

...later...

```
#+call retX(x=6)
```

as I would like to be able to define a block such as

```python
#+begin_src python :var x=5
<<retX(x)>> * <<retX(x=6)>>
#+end_src
```

and similiar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With python you probably have to use a :session to get persistence between src blocks. I like `:results output` personally, and use print statements where I want them.

You can probably do this as follows:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python :session :results output
def retX(x):
    return x
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:

#+BEGIN_SRC python  :session :results output
print(retX(x=6))
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: 6


#+BEGIN_SRC python  :session :results output :var x=5
print(retX(x) * retX(x=6))
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: 30
```

Comment: python was just an example, hoping more for a c/c++ setup. But maybe I can use cling or MIR for that. Thanks.

Comment: are you looking for noweb instead then? https://orgmode.org/manual/Noweb-Reference-Syntax.html

Comment: limitation might be that you should C-c C-c the "retX" block before you run others.